How do I remove all my YouTube comments at once using the browser console?
I have over 3000 YouTube comments on my Google account, and deleting them one by one is impractical.
Is there a way to delete all my comments at once using JavaScript in the browser console without deleting my channel?

With YouTube Data API v3 Comments: delete endpoint you can delete 200 comments per day with the default quota.

It is very simple and easy to do.
Simple Way
You can simply open the console in your Google My Activity section and paste this short code:
document.querySelectorAll("[aria-label*='Delete activity item']").forEach(button => {
    button.click();
});

Make sure to leave the tab open for a few minutes to ensure all delete requests are processed by Google.

Explanation
The code selects all elements with an aria-label containing 'Delete activity item' and clicks each one to trigger the deletion of your comments.
This automates the process, saving you from manually deleting each comment.
